# Iteration for each line retrieved from a database in talend

Tags: json, talend

I have been looking for some documentation but couldn't find any. I'm still new to Talend

I have a tAmazonMysqlInput retreiving some info from a database and for each line retreived, I would like to call an api (toofr) and display a result in a array (actually tLogRow_1).

Here is actually my situation : [image: Actual situation]

I don't know how to iterate for each line the right part of the call. The call and the display without the mysqlInput is running.
How to do this ?

Thanks in advance ! :D

Comment: you can use tIterateToFlow component after tAmazonMysqlInput.

Comment: Also, this looks fine. What doesn't work?

Comment: Recently saw that it worked (just did not understood) but now I do have a problem with the deserialization of the JSON. Gonna ask another question for that. Thx anyway :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use a tLoop, to count the number of lines you can use tFileRowCount.